# Finding location of duplicates from text

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, text, awk

I have data formatted like this:

```
1;string1
2;string2
...
n;stringn
```

The first column is id-number and second contains text string. Text strings may contain numbers, letters and characters such as `/.()?!`. Id-numbers are equal to line numbers. I am trying to find out duplicates in these text strings. I looking to get information like this:

```
String of id 1 is duplicated on lines/ids 4,6,7
String of id 2 is duplicated on lines/ids 11,25
```

So far I have done this using Awk command:

```
awk '/String of text/ {print FNR}' targetfile
```

And manually replaced the search string for each text string on my file. As the data sets are now larger, this is getting unpractical. Can my Awk command be improved so that it would automatically test each text string inside the file with other strings and output to information I am seeking? I though of using for-loop for this, but could not figure out how to make it work.

I could use other tool than Awk for this just as well, if there is a better solution. My system is Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: if only you could sort the file on the second field the task would've become almost trivial.

Comment: So if string1 is duplicated on lines 4,6,7, does that mean when we get to line 4 we need to say *string4 is duplicated on line 1,6,7* and on line 6 we need to say *string 6 is duplicated on line 1,4,7* ?

Comment: @DmitriChubarov So, if you do this, the file will be sorted on the second field... `awk -F';' '{print $2,$1}' OFS=';' file | sort`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this (explanation in the comments):

```
{ seen[$2] = seen[$2] $1 " " }               # remember where you saw strings
                                             # as string of numbers

END {                                        # in the end
  for(s in seen) {                           # for all strings you saw
    split(seen[s], nums, " ");               # split apart the line numbers again

    if(length(nums) > 1) {                   # if you saw it more than once
      line = s " is duplicated on lines";    # build the output line
      for(i = 1; i <= length(nums); ++i) {   # with all the line numbers where you 
        line = line " " nums[i]              # saw it
      }
      print line                             # and print the line
    }
  }
}
```

into a file, say `foo.awk`, and run `awk -F \; -f foo.awk filename`

You can also put it on one line like this:

```
awk -F \; '{ seen[$2] = seen[$2] $1 " " } END { for(s in seen) { split(seen[s], nums, " "); if(length(nums) > 1) { line = s " is duplicated in lines"; for(i = 1; i <= length(nums); ++i) { line = line " " nums[i] } print line } } }' filename
```

...but it's long enough that I'd use a file instead.